# Writing down the relation in the figure?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

[image]

---

---

So for the first question, I have written down the following:

- R = {(Tom, Tom)}
- R = {(Mia, Mia, Bob, Liv)}
- R = {(Liv, Liv, Tom, Noa)}
- R = {(Noa, Noa, Tom)}
- R = {(Gus, Gus, Tom, Liv)}
- R= {(Kim, Kim, Gus)}
- R = {(Bob, Bob)}

But should I make a single relation between all of these or is what I have done correct?

Comment: You redefine `R` several times. That looks wrong to me.

Comment: I think I should have made it Tom = {(Tom, Tom)}, Mia = {(Mia, Mia, Bob, Liv})

Comment: Ah, that looks pretty accurate! Thank you :D

Comment: Btw, do u know anything regarding cardinality? Isnt the cardinality of this set 8? Since it has 8 elements? I know it has more, but I mean several are repeated several times. Example: Mia is repeated 3 times, but isnt Mia just 1 element?

Comment: Judging from wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality ), I would say the cardinality of the Graph equals to the number of arrows. I.e. 15 (if I didn't miscount).

Comment: Can u stop making me feel dumb? Thanks man! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would describe the graph in one set with tuples (as it is described in your image):

$R=\{(Tom,Tom),(Mia,Mia),(Mia,Bob),(Mia,Liv),...\}$